# Best approach to a class that would run in background polling other API and saving data

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

So I have a website written in .NET Core C# and I would like to run a process in the background that would make API calls to other website and save the data in database.

I have created ApiAccessor class and would like to invoke the method from the controller (which uses dependency injections for it's database connection), but if I pass them to the ApiAccessor (it would be async) the connection is already disposed of. I've tried injecting it from the get go, but it will still say that the interfaces are disposed, by the time it finishes. I can only do await on it, but this would cause user to wait for too long. What approach should I take with this one? I am a newbie at DI. Maybe some Singleton class? I would still don't know how to pass dependency injections to singleton

ApiAccessor:

```
IUserAccount _userAccounts;

public ApiAccessor(IConfiguration configuration, IUserAccount userAccounts)
{
   _configuration = configuration;
   _userAccounts = userAccounts;
}

//...

MethodToPollApi(){

   var newUserIdToAdd = // just some kind of new data from api
   _userAccounts.Add(newUserIdToAdd) // accessing DB, that causes errors 

}
```

Controller:

```
void Index(){
  MethodToPollApi(); 
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Read up on `IHostedService` interface https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The purpose of a controller is to provide a response to a request. Once it has responded, its work is done. Running this from a controller method doesn't make sense. What if that `Index` is accessed 100 times? You'd have 100 processes polling the API.

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about it, it has it's checks for times etc, I just need to execute a piece of code that will poll the API and controller would control the timing of the event. I just need the controller to pass the info and the poll + save in db would be preformed by the accessor class

Answer (score 2):

I would consider an idea of using as called `background jobs`. There are a few popular frameworks for this type of solutions. Within them: custom implementation based on [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services), [Quartz.NET](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-quartz-net-hosted-service-with-asp-net-core/), [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/), and [many more](https://medium.com/@qwe16165850/scheduler-in-net-core-2-1-hangfire-tutorial-aca4ae4274a6) available.

I used to play with many of them, personally prefer [Hangfire](https://jonhilton.net/simple-background-jobs-with-hangfire-and-aspnet-core/) as it self bootstrapped, provide nice UI for jobs dashboard, and really easy to use - for instance, that is how triggering jobs light look like with it:

Run once immediately:

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget!"));
```

Run delayed:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Delayed!"), TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
```

Run repeating:

```
var jobId = RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"), Cron.Daily);
```

Pick up completed job and continue:

```
BackgroundJob.ContinueWith(jobId, () => Console.WriteLine("Continuation!"));
```

Comment: yes, i have it, but how do I give it access to database?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the answer from [@Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804385/dmitry-pavlov). With Hangfire you can do something like this.

```
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage("<Your connection string>"));
```

Hope this helps.